# Android - set Animation when onBackPressed() click - not work

Tags: android

In my main activity, i set this override method to improve my animation activity :

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_from_right, R.anim.pull_out_to_left);
```

In my second activity, i set onBackPressed() method to the main activity :

```
public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent backToMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(backToMain);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

It go back well, with the animation, but when I close the main activity that back from the second activity, the first main activity launched, still exist.

How to resolve this problem ? Thanks for your kindness response.

Comment: Hello Edward, welcome to SO. Please choose a valid answer if your question has been answered, thanks :)

Comment: Dear m0skit0 : Am I vote for the valid answer yet ? if yes, please tell me. bcos i just know how to do so. thanks for advice me

Comment: Yes, you selected the answer correcly. And again, welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your second activity, you don't have to create new intent to go back to main activity.

```
public void onBackPressed(){
   //you can do your other onBackPressed logic here..

   //Then just call finish()
   finish();
}
```

#### EDIT : After seeing OP's comment

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
  super.onPause();
  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.your_exit_animation_one, R.anim.your_exit_animation_two);
}

public void onBackPressed(){
   //you can do your other onBackPressed logic here..

   //Then just call finish()
   finish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But when I delete the calling new Intent, the Animation is not working.
Or did I do something wrong in my main activity: 

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pul_in_from_left, R.anim.pull_out_to_right);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: no need to call `finish()`, calling `super.onBackPressed();` will also do.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra : Still no animation loading :(
@-hotveryspicy : both finish() and super.onBackPressed() are working fine. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just add one override method

```
@Override
public void finish() {
   super.finish();
   overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
}
```